# How can I remove a node from selected html, without removing it from the current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm using jquery to grab HTML from my page and open it in a new window to print. I have to customize some of the styles so that the formatting works when I print it. I have a table on my main page that has `<colgroup>` to define the width of the columns, but when I print it, I've hidden the last column (since it has a button that there's no need for on the printout, and the button throws off the formatting when printed), but the width of the column remains due to the colgroup. If I remove the colgroup from the table, the non-hidden columns fill the width and formatting is perfect. I don't know how to delete the colgroup node on my print-window though, without deleting it from the origin window (which can't happen). This is my code for printing:

```
var newWin;

function printDetails() {
    var content = $("#pdf-area").html();
    var host = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
    var cssFiles = [
        host + "/Themes/MSD/Styles/template/ma-order-details-2.css",
        host + "/Scripts/libraries/zurb-responsive-tables/0.0.0/responsive-tables.css",
        host + "/Themes/MSD/Styles/template/checkout-cart-2.css",
        host + "/Themes/MSD/Styles/msdtheme.css",
        host + "/Themes/MSD/Styles/foundation.css",
        host + "/Themes/MSD/Styles/base.css",
        host + "/Themes/MSD/Styles/print.css"
    ];
    newWin = window.open();    
    cssFiles.forEach(function (file) {
        newWin.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + file + '" type="text/css" />');
    });
    newWin.document.write("<span class='please-wait'>Please wait...</span>");
    newWin.document.write("<div class='ma-order-details-2'>");
    newWin.document.write(content);
    newWin.document.write("</div>");
    newWin.document.close();
    newWin.focus();
    setTimeout(function () {
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }, 1000);   
}
```

I want to delete the colgroup from content, or delete it from newWin, but I don't know how to do this. $("colgroup").remove() will delete it from the origin page, not from the new window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of removing, you could be hiding it with `display:none` on your print stylesheet.

```
@media print {
    ...
    .colgroup {
         display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: that was the easiest fix!

Comment: I had no idea you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
var newPage = $('#newWin'); //Or whatever the new page will be
var content = $("#pdf-area").clone();

newPage.html(content.find('.colgroup').remove() );
```

The trick is cloning the content instead of grabbing the original and storing it in a variable, then you can modify it as you wish without changing the original.